# Regex for file name in a directory

Tags: regex

I have two files in a directory. `FileAbc_1.xml` and `FileAbc.xml`. I want write a regex that only select `FileAbc_1.xml`.

My regex is : `FileAbc.*.xml`

It is picking up both file names but I only want `FileAbc_1.xml`. Any help would great favor.

Comment: change the asterix `*` to a `+` it will make it match 1 or more of any character. You should also escape the dot before `xml` `FileAbc.+\.xml`

Comment: I'd go with `FileAbc_\d+\.xml` to allow any number of digits after `_`. It is more precise than `.+` that matches any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you
FileAbc_[0-9]+.xml

Answer (score 0):

That should just be: `FileAbc_\d\.xml`

(assuming there's never more than one digit after the underscore)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this for anything that will start with FileAbc and end with XML `FileAbc.+\.xml`.